# how can i separate the numbers multiple by 9 in 1 to 1000 numbers using javascript?

Tags: javascript

Here I am trying to display multiples of 9 in one side and remaining in another side from 1 to 1000 numbers. but only 9 multiples are displaying how can i display remaining numbers on another side?

```js
var i;
for (i=1;i<=1000;i++){
if (i % 9 == 0)
{
document.writeln(i);
document.write("<br>");
//document.write(i);
}
/*else if (i % 9){
document.write(i);
document.write("<br>");
}*/
}
```

Comment: Do you want to show the non-multiples of 9 on the left side like a column? Please elaborate

Comment: What is other side? You mean in some sort of table structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that by first adding two div in HTML, And then simply add the the value of i in div like if i % 9 == 0 then we add this value to first div else we add this value to second div using simple javascript code.
You can access first and second div by using document.getElementById("div_id");

```
<style>
    .box{
        width: 25%;
        float: left;
    }
</style>
<div id="div1" class="box"></div>
<div id="div2" class="box"></div>
<script>
    var i;
    var div1_output = "", div2_output = "";
    var div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
    var div2 = document.getElementById("div2");
    for (i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
        if (i % 9 == 0) {
            div1_output += i + "<br>";
        }
        else if (i % 9){
            div2_output += i + "<br>";
        }
    }
    div1.innerHTML = div1_output;
    div2.innerHTML = div2_output;

</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create two `<ul>` elements, concatenate `"<li>" + i + "</li>"` to appropriate `ul` to index of `ul` returned by `.querySelectorAll()`

```js
var ul = document.querySelectorAll("ul");
var i;
for (i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
  ul[i % 9 == 0 ? 0 : 1].innerHTML += "<li>" + i + "</li>";
}
```

```css
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 125px;
}

ul:nth-of-type(2) {
  left: 250px;
}
```

```html
<ul><li>multiples of 9</li></ul><ul><li>not multiples of 9</li></ul>
```